# ROC curve of the testing dataset

Tags: r, machine-learning

I am using caret packages to compare different models.

After training a model, how to find the ROC area.

```
# Split data 
a<- createDataPartition(data$target, p = .8, list = FALSE)
train <- data[ a,]
test <- data[-a,]

myControl = trainControl(
    method = "cv",
    summaryFunction = twoClassSummary,
    classProbs = TRUE,
    verboseIter = FALSE,
)

model_knn = train(
    target ~ .,
    train,
    method = "knn",
    metric = "ROC",
    tuneLength = 10,
    trControl = myControl)
```

For example, this is one of the models built. If I do the following, I can get the ROC curve of my training set. But to get the ROC of my testing data set?

```
model_knn
plot(model)
```

Comment: `plot(model_knn)` don't give you ROC curve rather it provide the change in ROC as the number of neighbors changes to select the optimum number of neighbors. The number of neighbor providing the maximum ROC is selected as optimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have not provided any data, I am using Sonar data. You can use the following code to make ROC plot for test data

```
library(caret)
library(MLeval)

data(Sonar)

# Split data 
a <- createDataPartition(Sonar$Class, p=0.8, list=FALSE)
train <- Sonar[ a, ]
test <- Sonar[ -a, ]

myControl = trainControl(
  method = "cv",
  summaryFunction = twoClassSummary,
  classProbs = TRUE,
  verboseIter = FALSE,
)

model_knn = train(
  Class ~ .,
  train,
  method = "knn",
  metric = "ROC",
  tuneLength = 10,
  trControl = myControl)

pred <- predict(model_knn, newdata=test, type="prob")
ROC <- evalm(data.frame(pred, test$Class, Group = "KNN"))
```

[image]

Comment: is 0.9 the area of the ROC curve? 
What does Group 1 mean

Comment: Yes, 0.9 is the area under the ROC curve. Group indicate the model name. I have modified the code to show the model name instead of Group1.

Comment: Thank you. Can I just print out the AUC instead of the graph if I want to further process it?

Comment: You can use `ROC$stdres` to have AUC value.

Comment: When I run ROC <- evalm(data. frame(pred, test$Class, Group = "KNN")) with my dataset, it shows other plots.

Comment: But I use your dataset instead, everything is normal

Comment: Without seeing your data it is very hard to say anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239525/discussion-between-user16971617-and-bappa-das).